# No monobehavior in Unity3D .js files

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

For a personal project, I'm trying to replicate elements of the C# program in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBVim8kEhK8&list=PLRf-PfhVvwFDWrHVWYj9tiRze0rtB5Sn0) but in javascript (in Unity3D). I'm using three different scripts, and for each file, Unity is telling me there are "no Monobehavior scripts in this file, or their names do not match the file name".

I know that for C# Monobehavior must be declared, but for JS it's inherent, so the issue hasn't made sense to me. I've triple-checked my file hierarchies and all the names/paths are correct. Even creating a new, blank .js file within the project returns the same error message.

Comment: hi Tyler, so you know you *can not* use "unityscript" now, it is deprecated.  it's unlikely you will get the specific problem to work.  Do note, fortunately it's just literally easier (and far faster) to just use and learn c#.  (Hence, "unityscript" is out.)

Comment: if you have any c# questions ask here for instant answers  :)

Comment: Joe, thanks for that info. I presume by "unityscript" you mean javascript within Unity3D? (I'm still figuring out the significance of each of these many languages)

Comment: hi Tyler, "unityscript" (very often incorrectly referred to as "javsacript") was an early language offered by Unity, a slight variation on javascript as such. Originally as well as c# they offered "boo" and "unityscript".  the bottom line is you have to go c# today, or you are torturing yourself.  if you're a new and/or hobbyist programmer, that's great, zillions of people are having fun with Unity, the good news is it is genuinely easier w/ c#.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! Thanks for the help.